# django : rename in admin panel does not work

Tags: django, django-models

When i change the primary key in the admin panel and choose the save button a new recrod is created.

But i want to rename the primary key.

models.py:

```
class Firma(models.Model):

firma = models.CharField(
    primary_key=True,
    max_length=50,
    db_column='Firma',
    help_text='Firma',
    verbose_name = 'Firma',
)

def __str__(self):
    return self.firma
```

admin.py:

```
class FirmaAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ( 'firma', )
    ordering = ('firma',)
```

I use Django 3.2.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this worked for me

```
import uuid

firma = models.CharField(
    primary_key=True,
    max_length=255,
    db_column='Firma',
    help_text='Firma',
    verbose_name = 'Firma',
    default=uuid.uuid4,

)

def __str__(self):
    return self.firma
```

Comment: Same behaviour. I have added  "default=uuid.uuid4," to the firma class run,  "manage.py makemigrations" and "manage.py migrate" and restarted the server.

When i change the pk from "test" to "test 2" and click the save button. I got the message "The Firma “test 2” was changed successfully." but django added an additional record.